# Connecting to the Azure speech translation service

Tags: microsoft-translator

In the speech translation using a microphone example here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-translate-speech-csharp

There is this piece of code

`var config = SpeechTranslationConfig.FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");`

But the service does not have a region. It is listed as "non-region" and the resource shows "global" in the Azure dashboard. So what service region should be entered in the example?

I have tried different regions but the connection keeps failing. I know the key is correct because I have successfully got a token using the key and endpoint `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0`.

I have tried the `FromEndpoint` version of the constructor giving the endpoint and key (avoiding the need to give a region) but this fails too.

Has anybody got this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-translate-speech-csharp is the documentation of the new Speech Service, which has just become generally available in Sept 2018. Here is a blog post regarding that: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/global-scale-ai-with-azure-cognitive-services/.

You can find regions info of the new Speech Service from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/regions. If your subscription doesn't show a region, that's probably because you are currently using the Bing Speech API, which is going to be retired on 10/15/2019. Please see the retirement notice on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/home. Please migrate to the new Speech Service before 10/15/2019. Here is the migration guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-migrate-from-bing-speech.

If you still have questions, please visit the Speech Service support page: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/support.

Hope this helps.